# How to add more Intervals Response Time Overview for JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Currently I am generating graph for Jmeter Results using Jtl by

```
Jmeter -g <jtfile> -o <Location>
```

When I look Response Time Over View It has the following intervals.

X- Axis -> Response time Ranges
Y- Axis -> Number of response

X- Axis  has range

```
- Request having <= 500ms, 
- b/w 500ms to 1500ms, 
- > 1500 ms and 
- Request in Error
```

Y- Axis --> Number of responses.

Now I need more intervals on X-Axis to present it in report.

Need Like

```
 - < 2000 ms, 
 - b/w 2000 - 5000, 
 - b/w 5000-1000ms 
 - >10000ms and 
 - request in error..
```

Is it configurable??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **change** these `500` and `1500` defaults by amending the following JMeter Properties:

```
jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_satisfied_threshold=500
jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_tolerated_threshold=1500
```

There is no way to add more thresholds without patching JMeter source code, however you can play with `jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_per_transaction` property to set custom values on per/transaction basis.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [JMeter HTML Reporting Dashboard: General Settings](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#configuration_general)
- [JMeter Properties Reference: Reporting Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#reporting)

Comment: I have changed jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_satisfied_threshold = 2000 and jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_tolerated_threshold= 5000 but there is no change in the graph.. also I did not see jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_per_transaction in user.properties

Comment: You need to re-generate the dashboard after the changes

Comment: It was commented..I have enabled that parameter and it is working fine.

Comment: So Satified threshold, b/w satisfied threshold tolerated and more than tolerated.. this is the actual interval. correct? we can not have more intervals.. right?